# Content security issue in Angular 5 app on Heroku

Tags: angular, content-security-policy

I recently upgraded my Angular 4.x app to Angular 5.0.0 and have the issue of a "Not Found" Text being displayed on the URL of my hosted app and a 404 thrown by Heroku.

[my app on heroku](http://swissrugbystats-frontend.herokuapp.com/)

When I look into the console I see around 5 errors about Content Security Policy (CSP)

The errors all look more or less like this:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at self (“default-src
>   http://swissrugbystats-frontend.herokuapp.com”).

I have 0 errors while deploying (deploying via `git push heroku`, running it on a express server with `node server.js`). The app worked fine with the same setup before upgrading to angular 5.0.0.

Also when I start the app locally it runs perfectly fine.

My server.js is pretty basic:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

// Run the app by serving the static files
// in the dist directory

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

// For all GET requests, send back index.html
// so that PathLocationStrategy can be used

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});

// Start the app by listening on the default
// Heroku port

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Do I have to explicitly add a csp configuration like this: https://ponyfoo.com/articles/content-security-policy-in-express-apps ?

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ch-swissrugbystats-angular2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "build": "ng build",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "deploy": "git push origin && git push heroku"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.10-4905443",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.0.0",
    "angular2-oauth2": "^1.3.10",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.4.3",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.6.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.0.46",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.8.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.6.0",
    "npm": "5.5.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the solution was quite simple. Basically The build was never triggered on heroku, so the `dist` folder and its contents were not present at all.

The only thing I had to do was add the following line in `scripts` section of the `package.json`:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "ng build --aot --prod",
```

More about the heroku specific build steps: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#heroku-specific-build-steps

The article I initially followed to setup the deployment on Heroku: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-cli-deployment-host-your-angular-2-app-on-heroku-3f266f13f352

In the article they use the `postinstall` script, but I decided to use the heroku one, because I don't want it to trigger after every install locally.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to use npm package `serve` instead of using `server.js` script